# OnClientClick not working for Imagebutton hidden fileupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, file-upload

I am working on Asp.net form as follows

```
<form runat="server" id="form">
                <label>Select Category <span>*</span></label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>Mobiles</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Electronics and Appliances</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Cars</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Bikes</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Furniture</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>General</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <label>Ad Title <span>*</span></label>

                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_title" class="phone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <label>Ad Description <span>*</span></label>
                <%--<textarea class="mess" placeholder="Write few lines about your product"></textarea>--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Body" class="mess" placeholder="Write few lines about your product" TextMode="multiline" Style="resize: none" Width="770px" Height="150px" Wrap="true" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"></asp:TextBox>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="upload-ad-photos">
                    <label>Photos for your ad :</label>
                    <div class="photos-upload-view">

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="return chooseFile();" ImageUrl="Images/Capture.JPG" runat="server" />

                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadControl" runat="server" Visible="False" />


                        <div id="messages">
                            <p>Status Messages</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                </div>
                <div class="personal-details">

                    <label>Your Name <span>*</span></label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_name" class="name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <label>Your Mobile No <span>*</span></label>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_phn" class="phone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <label>Your Email Address<span>*</span></label>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_email" class="email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <p class="post-terms">By clicking <strong>post Button</strong> you accept our <a href="terms.html" target="_blank">Terms of Use </a>and <a href="privacy.html" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a></p>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="post_sub" Text="Post" type="submit" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </form>
```

Where I want to call a hidden fileupload when Imagebutton is clicked using JavaScript as follows:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function chooseFile() {
        document.getElementById("#FileUploadControl").click();
        alert("grt");
        return false;

    }
</script>
```

But, I was not able to call the function instead page reloads, as you can see I am returning false in the function also. Please guide me to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the `Visible` property of the FileUpload Control to `false`. Therefore it does not exist on the client side. The `Visible` property is not the same as `display:none` in HTML/CSS.

You should do something like this:

```
<span style="display: none">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />
</span>
```

And it's always better to use the `ClientID` instead of hard coding the ID of the FileUpload Control.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function chooseFile() {
        document.getElementById("<%= FileUploadControl.ClientID %>").click();
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use  [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) you shouldn't mention `#` since it already searches for id attribute, in your current state it will look for id `#FileUploadControl` which is not your element id. change your code to this:

```js
function chooseFile() {
    document.getElementById("FileUploadControl").click();
    alert("grt");
    return false;

}
```

```html
 <form runat="server" id="form">
                    <div class="photos-upload-view">

                        <img id="ImageButton1"  OnClick="return chooseFile();" src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/office/PNG/512/Computer_Hardware/mouse_left_click-512.png" style="widdth:40px;height:40px;" />

                        <input type="file" ID="FileUploadControl" runat="server" style="display:none;" />

                </div>
    
            </form>
```

Comment: Thats true I have remove the '#' but still it is not working as, chooseFile() function itself is not called as I can't see any alert.

Comment: @AnirudhRaj sorry i don't know jsp but i'll add a working demo with html and JavaScript.

Comment: @AnirudhRaj maybe remove runat="server" and try.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, number one is you using # of you document.getElementById("#FileUploadControl") it's wrong and you should use it without # document.getElementById("FileUploadControl").

second thing if you use Visible="False" attribute it not rendering the HTML element, without that you can use below two methods.

1. FileUploadControl.Style["visibility"] = "hidden" in your backend file
2. using following css class for hide

```js
 function chooseFile() {
        document.getElementById("FileUploadControl").click();
        alert("grt");
        return false;

    }
```

```css
  .setDisplayNone {
      display:none;
  }
```

```html
  <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadControl" runat="server" CssClass="setDisplayNone" />
```